# If Earth suddenly stops rotating, will be thrown at 465 m/s?

Tags: earth, rotation, celestial-mechanics

If Earth suddenly stops rotating, will be thrown at 465 m/s ?

Comment: this would be for the PHYSICS.SE site - no connection to astronomy

Comment: Depends on your latitude too. At north pole, you might just fall over. Later, the winds would blow you around something awful.